# How do duplicate defense stats work in Loop Hero?

Tags: loop-hero

I came across a blue shield that listed two different numbers for defense: defense 18 and defense 6. How do duplicate defense stats work? Do they stack?

[image: Shield with defense 18 and defense 6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they stack. The first number is the shield's base value, the second one is its special property because it's a blue (magic) item, the sum makes the shield's total defense stat. In this case the shield just has additional defense, but it could be life, regeneration, etc. Yellow items have more special stats, and orange ones have the most although iirc their base stat (like damage for a weapon) is usually lower to compensate.